# Changing drive letter of boot VHD host drive?

Tags: boot, vhd, drive-letters

I'm loving the new Boot-to-VHD feature in Win7! But I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to change the drive letter (while booting from a VHD file) of the drive that's hosting the VHD boot file.

I have multiple hard drives/partitions and I'd like the drive letter mappings to be as similar as possible when booting from the physical drive and when booting from a VHD. By default, the physical host drive is showing up as drive D: when booting from the VHD file and I'd like to change it to something like "X:" so the other mappings can be the same in either case. The typical method of changing the drive letter using the Disk Management tool from the control panel doesn't work, I assume because the drive is currently being used (obviously the VHD file I'm booted from is open).

Anyone have any bright ideas on how perhaps I could set up the system to change the drive letter on automatically on the next boot? This isn't a critical need of course, but I thought I'd see if anyone had any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this was my bad. Windows 7 does allow you to change the drive letter of the physical drive hosting the VHD. It's even smart enough to recognize that's what it's doing and put up a warning message to that effect.

What was preventing me from changing the drive letter was that Windows had placed the page file on that drive and you can't change the drive letter of a drive with the page file on it. It's interesting that Windows won't put the pagefile.sys file on a VHD drive but will find a physical drive to put it on instead.